# Resolve factory method as constructor parameter

Tags: dryioc

I have an instance constructor that takes a String as a runtime parameter, followed by several service parameters. I'd like to be able to specify the string at runtime and let DryIoc take care of the rest of the parameters

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42739535/657572) answer shows how to do it for simple resolution, however, if the object with the factory method parameter is itself a constructor parameter, the resolution fails as DryIoc attempts to resolve the string.

```cs
public class BigBrother
{
    public BigBrother(Camera camera) {
        // Is watching you
    }
}

public class Camera
{
    public Camera(Func<String, Incident> incidentFactory)
    {
        var incident = incidentFactory("Something bad was seen");
    }
}

public class Incident
{
    private String _title;
    public Incident(String title, ICctvService cctvService, IUserService userService, ILoggingService logger)
    {
        _title = title;
        // Things happened
    }
}
```

Resolving BigBrother in the above code fails because the parameters of camera cannot be resolved.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Show me the registrations for the services in the example. From what I see at the moment, everything should be resolved just fine.